# How can I send authenticated email using Swiftmailer in a Yii2 application?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer, email-validation

I need to tell SwiftMailer to require authentication to be able to send email from my web sites.
I've searched around for a few days but cannot find which parameter to specify.

My hosting company say that I have to use Pear to do it, but I imagine that yii would handle it.

My setup is

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
                'host' => 'lss1.layerip.com',
                'port' => '465',
                'username' => xxx@yyy.com',
                'password' => ppppp
```

I'm using the advanced app, and the hosting provider is new to me (Jolt).

This is what they recommend:

```
    <?php
      require_once "check_the_correct_path_above/Mail.php";
      $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
      $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
      $subject = "Hi!";
      $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
      $host = "ssl://mail.example.com";
      $port = "465";
      $username = "smtp_username";
      $password = "smtp_password";
      $headers = array ('From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject);
      
      $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => $host,
          'port' => $port,
          'auth' => true,
          'username' => $username,
          'password' => $password));
      
      $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
      
      if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
       } else {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
       }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you supply the errors you are receiving when sending please?

Please send the swiftmail configuration in your config file as well.  I am looking to see your

```
filetransport
```

definition.

Comment: Connection to tcp://lss1.layerip.com:465 Timed Out